# Button's don't work when clicked on, Code is correct

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button

I tried test files like HelloWorld and Count Down timer. Neither of the buttons on my app seem to work. These segments of code are ones I downloaded from the internet, and they have been reported to work. I don't know what the issue could be. I am also very new eclipse and android app programming.

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:text="CountDown Timer Demo"
    />
<Button
    android:text="Seizure Detected"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<Button
    android:text="Override"
    android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>

<Button
    android:text="click me"
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="sexy"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

CountDownTest.java >In the src folder

```
package com.example.epilepsytestapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CountDownTest extends Activity {
    Button start, stop;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.start);
        stop = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        tv  = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText("10"); // startting from 10.

        final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(10000,1000);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

        public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            System.out.println("Timer Completed.");
            tv.setText("Timer Completed.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000)+"");
            System.out.println("Timer  : " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Helloworld.java

```
package com.example.epilepsytestapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           //@Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloWorld.this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
         });        
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.epilepsytestapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".CountDownTest"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.epilepsytestapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
                    android:name=".CountDownTest"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What should happen? What happens instead?

Comment: When I click the buttons on the emulator, they should work. For the button "Click me", (hello world) it should output "hello world". For the CountDownTest, when I click the button "Seizure Detected", it should start a visible count down timer from 10 on the tv. When I click the button, "Override", it should stop the timer. However, when I click any of the buttons, nothing happens. At all. I can click them as many times as I want, but nothing happens.

Comment: remove `this`  before `findViewById`

Comment: @user2246076 : probably you forget to start `CountDownTest` Activity from `HelloWorld` Activity(if `HelloWorld` is main Activity) then use `startActivity(new Intent(HelloWorld.this,CountDownTest.class))` on button click in `HelloWorld` Activity. and also make sure you have registered `CountDownTest` as Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I actually added "this" to it, because someone suggested it would work better that way. It didn't work with or without "this". Could there be an issue with my emulator?

Comment: @user2246076 : why you have commented `//@Override` before onClick method? plz uncomment it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K How do I register CountDownTest as an Activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @user2246076 : ok just add it as `<activity android:name=".CountDownTest"/>` before `</application>` in your current  AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K Thanks for trying to help, it still doesn't work. But I also noticed, I had android:name="com.example.epilepsytestapp.MainActivity" written in the AndroidManifest.xml. I really don't know what the issue is.

Comment: @user2246076 : ok just add your latest AndroidManifest.xml with question then i will try to help u

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I edited the original post too include the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: @user2246076 : replace `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
                    android:name=".CountDownTest"/>` with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` then try it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K no luck man :(, does the code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

try this.Your hello world code

```
package com.example.epilepsytestapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
         });        
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry that doesn't seem to work either. MainActivity in that spot doesn't even compile. Could there be something wrong with my emulator?

Comment: Are you able to run a new project (which has "hello world" in it by default) in emulator? Refer this link if you need http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/